# Bleeding Underfloor Heating Without Manifold (with pics!)?

Tags: hvac, heating, water-circulating-heating

We have house extension with underfloor heating. Underfloor heating was added after the extension was built. It is very unevenly heated - like 20% of the area. It was like that since we've bought the house.
Recently I got my hands on thermal camera and this is what it is showing:

[image: Thermal image of my undrfloor heating]

Hot water goes through a few loops and then cools down very quickly and does not finish the loop. I've spoken to my favourite plumber (he's in another city) and he suggested that there is air trapped, and ask to find a manifold and bleed from there.

But this is all I found:

[image: Left red tap is start of the underfloor loop. Right red tap is end of underfloor loop]

There is no manifold, only 2 taps. The underfloor heating is in the extension which was built after the house, and on top of that the underfloor heaing was added after the extension was built, so quite likely there was no space/opportunity to add manifold.

Left red tap is start of the underfloor loop. Right tap is end of the underfloor loop. I've confirmed that by shutting left valve and firing up the boiler - underfloor loop stayed cold.

Now this is what I see in thermal camera:

[image: Left tap is hot, right tap is cold]

Left tap (start of the loop) is piping hot, but no hot water comes back from the loop. Even though it is connected to the hot pipe on the return!

So I am suspecting that there is a lot of air trapped in the floor loop, but there is no valve to bleed that air.

I am thinking I'll slowly undo that right nut that holds the return pipe in place and see if I get any air out of the system, and shut it back when I start getting water coming through. Basically imitate the bleed valve by undoing the pipe connection.
[image: Undo this nut to let air out?]

Questions:

- does assumption about trapped air sound plausable?
- am I proposing an insane thing to try bleeing it by undoing pipe connection? Am I going to trash my heating system?
- should I get a qualified plumber for this job?
- anything else I should try?

This is UK. [Hi-res pic without annotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7k08.jpg)

Comment: Stone cold return water suggests that all of the heat radiated out of the water, no? I imagine the return water's temperature increases as the flow rate through the circuit increases.

Comment: If the utility area picture is at a lower elevation than the heated floor, then any trapped air doesn't want to flow downhill through the sag in your hoses.

Comment: @popham it is all pretty much all on the same level. Your first comment about flow rate got me thinking - I've shut all the radiators off and opened up underfloor loop and turned on the boiler full blast - waiting for the results now.